# Getting Exception as "Can't map name to dispid: IniRead" while using Iniread function of AutoItX in java

Tags: jacob

I am using AutoItx and Jacob library and trying to read the ini file using below command in Java.

**autoItxObj.iniRead("C:\Users\path\Locale.ini","LOCALE","en_US","KEY NOT FOUND");**

but i am getting exception as **Can't map name to dispid: IniRead**.

How to proceed with that.

Please help.
Any help appreciated!!! :)